# How do I get the .exe name of a C# console application?

Tags: c#, fileversioninfo

I'm debugging "xiixtasks.exe", a C# console-mode application in VS2008.

I'm trying to get the version info from xiixtasks.exe.

When I try "Process.GetCurrentProcess()", it gives me the filename and version info for vshost.exe, NOT xiixtasks.exe:

```
  // WRONG: this gives me xiixtasks.vhost.exe, version 9.0.30729.1
  //        I *want* "xiixtasks.exe", version 1.0.0.1024
  System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fi =
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileVersionInfo;
```

What should I be doing instead?

Thank you in advance!

======================================================

Solution:

1) The initial problem was indeed the IDE's "vshost" wrapper.
   One workaround would have been to change the build settings.

2) Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase is an *excellent* solution - thank you!.
   It works inside and outside the debugger.

3) Unfortunately, when I tried calling it with a function that expected a normal file path (instead of a URI like GetExecutingAssembly()" gives you), it died with a "Uri formats are not supported" exception.

4) Final solution: call GetExecutingAssembly(), then Uri.LocalPath ():

```
...
else if (cmdArgs.cmd.Equals(CmdOptions.CMD_SHOW_VERSION))
{
    string codeBaseUri = 
       Urifile.System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    string codeBase =
        new Uri (codeBaseUri).LocalPath;
    string sVersion = Util.GetWindowsVersion(codeBase);
    System.Console.WriteLine ("version({0}): {1}: ",
        Util.Basename(codeBase), sVersion);
}
```

Thank you once again, all!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Full Path of your assembly:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.Dump();
```

You can always extract the name with `Path.GetFileName`:

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
string name = Path.GetFileName(codeBase);
```

Comment: I recommend this. string fullname = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

Comment: You also could use Name property of ManifestModule: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.Name

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you are running inside the IDE in debug with the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox enabled. In which case, the current process ***is*** `xiixtasks.vshost.exe` - it is a shell exe used to help debugging. You need to disable that checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Exactly, if you run the application outside of the IDE, it should return xiixtasks.exe.

Comment: Addendum - if I call .GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase instead of Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule, then it works both inside and outside of the IDE, regardless of debug settings.

Answer (score 5):

This would also get you name / version

```
name: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
version: = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this to get the version:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

And this to get the name:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().ToString()
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what info you want, you can use a variety of calls:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's actually what I would expect as it is in fact executing the vshost file in debug mode.

If you don't want it to execute the vshost file but rather your exe directly, you need to go into your project settings and disable the vshost debugging option.

Answer (score 2):

The 'vshost.exe' wrapper is generally only enabled for Debug builds, and it's also not necessary to use it, so perhaps you should just consider turning it off under your project settings (Debug tab, uncheck 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process' at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

try

`var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();`

Comment: Mostly this: string exeName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

If you will get the exception like "URI format is not supported" While Copying the xml file from     one directory to the another by using the following code.

```
string path=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
DirectoryInfo dir=new DirectoryInfo(path+"\\App2");
FileInfo[] Files=dir.GetFiles();
```

then convert it into the URI like.

```
string path =Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase); 
URI uri = new URI(path); 
string FileName = Path.Combine(uri.LocalPath, "\\App2"+file.Name);
```

then use it to get the files.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
using System;
namespace DemoApplication{
   public class Program{
      public static void Main(){
         string currentExecutable =
         System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
         Console.WriteLine($"Current Executable Name: {currentExecutable}");
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-executable-in-chash

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 6 Console App (or later)

```
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

will give you the full path of the executing assembly DLL.

To get the executable name you can replace the extension:

```
string dllPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string exePath = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dllPath)}.exe";
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(exePath);
```

**References**

- [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?view=net-8.0)
- [Assembly.Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-8.0)
- [FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo?view=net-8.0)