# Getting name of the current executable from assembly vs process?

Tags: c#, .net

This is a follow up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616588/37759) (and it's comments).   What is the difference between getting an executable name from assembly vs process?

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase
```

vs

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
```

I'm assuming these will be the same all the time? No? Are there pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ProcessName is the name of the Operating System host process.

Assembly CodeBase points to an assembly inside a given process. The same assembly can be hosted by different processes.

Answer (score 6):

They're not necessarily the same. Compile these two programs as console applications in the same directory:

```
// In Test.cs, compile to Test.exe
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewDomain").ExecuteAssembly("Test2.exe");
    }
}

// In Test2.cs, compile to Test2.exe
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

class Test2
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0}",
                          Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        Console.WriteLine("Entry assembly: {0}", 
                          Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Process: Test
Entry assembly: file:///c:/Users/Jon/Test/Test2.EXE
```

Answer (score 3):

No, they needn't return the same values.

As it happens, I ran into this "gotcha" recently: they can return DIFFERENT values depending on whether you're running the .exe directly, or from inside of the MSVS debugger:

[How do I get the .exe name of a C# console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881148/how-do-i-get-the-exe-name-of-a-c-sharp-console-application)

That's just one example - I'm sure there might be others.

'Hope that helps!